# How do I center a Bootstrap div with a 'spanX' class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and am trying to center a div(span7) like that:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="span7">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

my css code is:

```
#main{
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

But it isn't set at the center. How can i set center?

**EDIT**

`span7` is now `col-7` in Bootstrap 4 and row-fluid is deprecated(Instead of this, use `container-fluid` and `row`).

Comment: Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `span7`.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Twitter's bootstrap `.span` classes are floated to the left so they won't center by usual means. So, if you want it to center your `span` simply add `float:none` to your `#main` rule.

**CSS**

```
#main {
 margin:0 auto;
 float:none;
}
```

Comment: better still, add a class called center, like so:
`.center
{
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}`
and add the center class to the desired element. This way it is reusable.

Comment: Sorry for being late, but I'm fronting this issue right now. I got how to center **one** `span*` column, but how do I center **multiple** columns? Even just two columns both set to `span6`.

Comment: @whatyouhide you can apply the same code that I used above with a class to the elements you wish to center. Check -spikyjt's comment above, with that method you can apply it to multiple elements.

Comment: @AndresIlich that way the columns are not placed side by side, but one above the other (in my very case).

Comment: @whatyouhide if you want to center a "group" of grid elements just place them inside a container, give it a width and center that instead. For example, if its two `.span3` grid elements, you can use `.span6` on the parent container and center that.

Comment: at desktop size, behavior is as expected (the `span7` element fills 7 columns and is centered; however, while slowly shrinking the screen, at one point the `span7` element _suddenly_ expands to fill the entire width.

Answer (score 34):

Incidentally, if your `span` class is even-numbered (e.g. `span8`) you can add an `offset` class to center it – for `span8` that would be `offset2` (assuming the default 12-column grid), for `span6` it would be `offset3` and so on (basically, half the number of remaining columns if you subtract the `span`-number from the total number of columns in the grid).

**UPDATE**
Bootstrap 3 [renamed a lot of classes](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) so all the `span*`classes should be `col-md-*` and the `offset` classes should be `col-md-offset-*`, assuming you're using the medium-sized responsive grid.

I created a quick demo here, hope it helps: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEyHd.

Comment: When you narrow down the browser window offset will become a problem instead of a solution. The browser will try to keep the offset area as a blank space so it will not behave the same way as margin: auto. The emtpy space will be kept there with the size proportional to the current window size.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski: Not exactly; I agree that it is not the same as `margin:auto`, however, the column will still be centered with respect to Bootstrap's 12-column grid.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski margin:auto doesn't centre the content of the div. So I don't really understand your comment...

Comment: As far as I understand the question is about putting the div in the center of the page and not centering the content of the div.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski: This doesn't center the content of the div. However, I now understand what you meant in your original comment; I assumed that Bootstrap's responsive grid was being used where resizing the browser would just collapse the columns. The problem you described would indeed happen with the non-responsive grid; however the div would still be centered with respect to the layout and also, the Bootstrap grid is now responsive by default.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone wants the true solution for centering BOTH images and text within a span using bootstrap row-fluid, here it is (how to implement this and explanation follows my example):

css

```
div.row-fluid [class*="span"] .center-in-span { 
   float: none; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   text-align: center; 
   display: block; 
   width: auto; 
   height: auto;
}
```

html

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
      <img class="center-in-span" alt="MyExample" src="/path/to/example.jpg"/>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
      <p class="center-in-span">this is text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

USAGE:
To use this css to center an image within a span, simply apply the .center-in-span class to the img element, as shown above.

To use this css to center text within a span, simply apply the .center-in-span class to the p element, as shown above.

EXPLANATION:
This css works because we are overriding specific bootstrap styling. The notable differences from the other answers that were posted are that the width and height are set to auto, so you don't have to used a fixed with (good for a dynamic webpage). also, the combination of setting the margin to auto, text-align:center and display:block, takes care of both images and paragraphs.

Let me know if this is thorough enough for easy implementation.

Comment: what is that `class*="span"` ? please also refer to any tutorial/doc on that type of selector.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

As of BS3 there's a `.center-block` helper class. From the docs:

```
// Classes
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

// Usage as mixins
.element {
  .center-block();
}
```

There is hidden complexity in this seemingly simple problem. All the answers given have some issues.

### 1. Create a Custom Class (Major Gotcha)

Create `.col-centred` class, but there is a major gotcha.

```
.col-centred {
   float: none !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

<!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-centred">
  Centred content.
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap 2 -->
<div class="span-6 col-centred">
  Centred content.
</div>
```

**The Gotcha**

Bootstrap requires columns add up to 12. If they do not they will overlap, which is a problem.  In this case the centred column will overlap the column above it. Visually the page may look the same, but mouse events will not work on the column being overlapped (you can't hover or click links, for example). This is because mouse events are registering on the centred column that's overlapping the elements you try to click.

**The Fixes**

You can resolve this issue by using a `clearfix` element. Using `z-index` to bring the centred column to the bottom will not work because it will be overlapped itself, and consequently mouse events will work on it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    I get overlapped by `col-lg-7 centered` unless there's a clearfix.
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 centred">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can isolate the centred column in its own row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7 centred">
    Look I am in my own row.
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2. Use col-lg-offset-x or spanx-offset (Major Gotcha)

```
<!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
  Centred content.
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap 2 -->
<div class="span-6 span-offset-3">
  Centred content.
</div>
```

The first problem is that your centred column must be an even number because the offset value must divide evenly by 2 for the layout to be centered (left/right).

Secondly, as some have commented, using offsets is a bad idea. This is because when the browser resizes the offset will turn into blank space, pushing the actual content down the page.

### 3. Create an Inner Centred Column

This is the best solution in my opinion. No hacking required and you don't mess around with the grid, which could cause unintended consequences, as per solutions 1 and 2.

```
.col-centred {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="centred">
        Look I am in my own row.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the width as 960px, or whatever you prefer, and you're good to go!

```
#main {
 margin: 0 auto !important;
 float: none !important;
 text-align: center;
 width: 960px;
}
```

(I couldn't figure this out until I fixed the width, nothing else worked.)