# Center table with Twitter Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that I would like the width to be *span5* and make it center horizontally.

How can I do this with Twitter Bootstrap 2?

Comment: Fix the width. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/bootstrap-css-center-span7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a new style -

```
.center-table
{
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  float: none !important;
}
```

and apply it to the table -

```
<table class="span5 center-table">
  <tr>
    <td>This is a centered table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just for knitpicking, to follow bootstraps "naming convention", you should rather call the class .table-centered xD

Comment: This DID work when I added it to the class for the containing div, the span12 div.  <div class="span12 table-center">  It DID NOT work when I added it to the class for the table.  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-center">

Comment: @ATSiem - That's because in your second code the table is 100% width and as such cannot be centered.  The answer is not for centering the contents of the table, its for centering the table itself.

Comment: It helps if you fix the width, in addition to play with margin and float.

Comment: The width is already fixed by the span5 class and does so in line with bootstrap.