# Center sidebar content in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to center sidebar. Here is my layout (which doesn't work):

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span9">
        ...
      </div>
    <div class="span3">
    //sidebar
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 center-block">
          //content which should be centered
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

center-block code I have taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/bootstrap-css-center-span7):

```
.center-block {
 margin:0 auto;
 float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.center-block {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
}
```

By using above code it will center the `center-block` Div not the content inside it, to align your content you need to add `text-align:center` in `.center-block` class like this:

```
.center-block {
    margin:0 auto; /*It will center the block*/
    float:none;
    text-align:center; /*It will center the content inside block*/
}
```

Comment: I do not want to center content, I want to center the content block

Comment: Is there any `width` defined for `row-fluid` or for `span3` or for `container-fluid` in your css?

Comment: it is fluid, so the value depends on resolution

Answer (score 0):

for `margin: 0 auto;` to work you need to also set a `width` on the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the content, try the following.

```
.center-block {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to center the text, I want to center the block itself

Comment: try to set a width for all parent divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set text-align property of the span3 to center.

```
div.span3
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Hope this will answer your question :)