# In a bootstrap responsive page how to center a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image: position a div at centre of a responsive page]

I need to create a responsive page using bootstrap by position a div at the centre of a page as like in the below mentioned layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/how-do-i-center-a-bootstrap-div-with-a-spanx-class

Comment: i need to center a div with the text(Responsive design using bootstrap) which should be present inside another full width col-lg-12 centered div as like in the layout.it would be helpful if i can get the sample code in fiddle

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Super cool update for 2024

WebKit Features in Safari 17.4 is adding a way to center vertically without using Flex/Grid by adding `align-content: center;` on any block element

```
div { align-content: center; } /* one-line vertical centering */
```

Soon is going to be available in all browsers

https://webkit.org/blog/15063/webkit-features-in-safari-17-4/#css

Update for Bootstrap 5

Simpler vertical grid alignement with flex-box

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div style="background:red">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution for Bootstrap 4

Simpler vertical grid alignement with flex-box

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div style="background:red">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution for Bootstrap 3

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 html, body, .container-table {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-table {
    display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background:red">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a simple example of a horizontally and vertically div centered in all screen sizes.

Comment: Maybe `class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"` sould be enough.

Comment: I have to position the div col-lg-12 vertically center in all screen sizes

Comment: I found the solution for you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/687/

the container must have height 100% otherwise you need to use position absolute

Comment: @ppollono, I guess your fildle example is not loading / referencing bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 62):

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    example
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vocasle/n4z8n0v2/)

Comment: this solution does not work when i open my site in the mobile.

Comment: Hi, what browser you were using? Did you load Bootstrap's stylesheets and javascript? It's working in Firefox and Chrome. Tested on all screen sizes.

Comment: I tested this by resizing my browser, as well as using a responsive website checker. Works for me.

Comment: this fix is breaking bootstrap default styles

Answer (score 41):

In **bootstrap 4**

to **center the children horizontally**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
justify-content-center
```

to **center the children vertically**, use bootstrap-4 class

```
 align-items-center
```

but remember don't forget to use d-flex class with these
it's a bootstrap-4 utility class, like so

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100px;">
    <div class="bg-primary">MIDDLE</div>    
</div>
```

**Note:** make sure to add bootstrap-4 utilities if this code does not work

Answer (score 20):

**Update for Bootstrap 4**

Now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, vertical alignment is easier. Given a full height flexbox div, just us `my-auto` for even top and bottom margins...

```
<div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="jumbotron my-auto">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/ayraB3tjSd/bootstrap-4-vertical-center

---

[Vertical center in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 8):

For centering a div assign three class names of bootstrap inside into a div:  `ml-0 mr-0 mx-auto`

Just look at the simple example below how it is being centered

```
<div class="bg-primary w-50 ml-0 mr-0 mx-auto text-center">
      Center
</div>
```

Comment: This one keeps the width of the content from going too small for low width screens.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to change anything in CSS you can directly write this in class and you will get the result.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 container justify-content-center">
  <div class="col" style="background:red">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it works for horizantal center only, i dont know why up?
queston asked for both (h and v).

Answer (score 4):

without display table and without bootstrap , i would rather do that

```
<div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background:red">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>


 html, body, .container-table {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-table {
    width:100vw;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.vertical-center-row {
   margin:auto;
  width:30%;
  padding:63px;
  text-align:center;

}
```

http://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/PbbWgQ

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple CSS rules that put any div in the center

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Links tend to become stale over time.

Comment: Also, this isn't the "bootstrap way" to achieve this.

Comment: @FuriousFolder, what is the BS way?

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4, use:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">...</div>
```

You can also change the position depending on what you want:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">...</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">...</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">...</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">...</div>
```

Reference [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
} 
.container{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Counter</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>0</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Decrease</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Increase</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

you can do also that way.

Answer (score 3):

Simply insert the class : `d-flex justify-content-center`  to the div that you want center. Such ;

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="asf" alt="text" >
</div>
```

Note : This works only If you uses Bootstrap 5.

I taken following code using : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ , follow it for more details.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Good answer ppollono. I was just playing around and I got a slightly better solution.
The CSS would remain the same, i.e. :

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But for HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="vertical-center-row">
        <div align="center">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to accomplish the layout with bootstrap is like this:

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div align="center">
            <div style="max-width: 200px; background-color: blueviolet;">
                <div>
                    <h1 style="color: white;">Content goes here</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

all I did was to add layers of divs that allowed me to center the div, but since I am not using percentages, you need to specify the max-width of the div to be center.

You can use this same method to center more than one column, you just need to add more div layers:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div align="center">
            <div style="max-width: 400px; background-color: blueviolet;">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="background-color: darkcyan;">
                        <h1 style="color: white;">Some content</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: blue;">
                        <p style="color: white;">More content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: that I added a div with column 12 for md, sm and xs, if you don't do this the first div with background color (in this case "blueviolet") will collapse, you will be able to see the child divs, but not the background color.

Answer (score 1):

For actual version of Bootstrap 4.3.1 use

**Style**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**Code**

```
<div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="jumbotron my-auto">
<!-- example content -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<h4 class="alert-heading">Title</h4>
<p>Desc</p>
</div>
<!-- ./example content -->
</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way ,but will still work

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
<div class="row h-100">
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 border">
    This div is in middle
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, For the example, I used a fixed height. I think it is doesn't affect the responsive scenario.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-secondary w-100" style="height: 300px;">
        <div class="bg-primary" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
<div class="bg-danger text-white">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet used and worked,

```
<div class="container-fluid py-5 h-100">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col col-md-8">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/52VtD/698/)

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="container" id="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">text
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="child">TEXT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#parent {    
    text-align: center;
}
#child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simplest solution will be adding one blank column in both sides like below:

```
  <div class="row form-group">

    <div class="col-3"></div>

    <ul class="list-group col-6">
      <li class="list-group-item active">Yuvraj Patil</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>
```