# how to horizontally center a responsive div?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Trying to **center** a div that will contain responsive adsense code.

example :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="adsense">adsense code here</div>
</div>
```

I can center the div if I type the exact measurement of the ad. so 728x90 is the max I want. At the moment I have a img as a temp placement and it works fine. Problem is if I type in exact px then it wont be responsive.

Any ideas please?

Ok this is my actual code...

```
<section class="main-content">
            <div class="top-banner">
                <img src="img/ad_top.jpg">
            </div>
</section>
```

(img is there as a placeholder for notepad++)

```
.main-content {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.top-banner {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

this just places the img left and not center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142606/in-a-bootstrap-responsive-page-how-to-center-a-div]

Comment: Then you can use `max-width`.

Comment: thanks Usman, you got it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you talking about? Horizontal centering is done with `margin: 0 auto;` it doesn't matter what size the container has.

Comment: Of course it works. It's the whole point. But if you do NOT use some sort of width-setting, it will be 100% wide, which is probably not what you want. Hence, use margin, but also use max-width (the absolute max you can tolerate), and a min-width at the smallest size ad possible. And you can set width in plenty of other measurements than `px`

Answer (score 0):

what do u think of this?:

```
.wrapper{
  width:100vw;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.adsense{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/pNNRNZ

Comment: That's better but it still doesnt center the div but i can see its behaving like i need it too...just need to tinker with it...lemme see if I can post my actual code i have up top

Comment: it does center the div. add .adsense{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center
} to align the text too