# Centering tables and making page responsive

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page full of fixed tables (6 of them). I made them with simple CSS but I want to put them in center for all devices and made the page responsible for all devices. I know it's just CSS but I'm so confused.

P.S I'm from my phone and I can't share my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap.

Comment: If you can't share your code then you can't get an answer.  Please read this [MCVE] - it doesn't need to be your exact code, just enough code to reproduce the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

```css
 html, body, .container-table {
    height: 100%;
}
.container-table {
    display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background:red">
        <table>
<tr>
<th>COL1</th>
<th>COL2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TD COL1</td>
<td>TD COL1</td>
</tr>
<table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As per your requirement need to used Responsive css like bootstrap or you can used **@media screen** for specific device

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    table{
        //your property;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks for your reply.  I know about media Queries but the problem isn't to make smaller the divs with mq but to adjust the divs to center

Comment: You need to  design css manually if you don't used like bootstrap then.

Comment: I'll try bootstrap. I never used before. Thanks. I'll update you after that. Thanks

Comment: Here is your answer table was in center please make your table in this center DIV [must click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142606/in-a-bootstrap-responsive-page-how-to-center-a-div)