# Bootstrap: two column centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a two-column centered layout with Bootstrap 3.1.
I've read this: [How do I center a Bootstrap div with a 'spanX' class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/how-do-i-center-a-bootstrap-div-with-a-spanx-class), but the content is stil aligned to the left. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="center">

    <div class="col-lg-3 gauche">
    Left div
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 corps">
    Right div
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.corps
{
    background-color: white;
}
.contenu
{
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
.center
{
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.gauche
{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Result is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G2Rq.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a container, remove the center div and add two blank col-lg-2 on either side so it adds up to 12 columns:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 gauche">
  Left div
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-5 corps">
  Right div
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome. If it helped please approve the answer.

Comment: Should use col-lg-offset-2 instead

Comment: You should use offsets instead

Comment: Thanks much much. after looking many solutions few hours - adding '<div class="col-lg-2" />' was the right solution.

Answer (score 13):

You would want to use a column offset class. If you are using a stock build of Bootstrap all of the column classes need to add up to 12. Your `col-lg-3` and `col-lg-5` only add up to 8 so adding a `col-lg-offset-2` should fix you up to center. Also, bootstrap has a built in centering class `container` i personally would use that. See below code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 gauche">
    Left div
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 corps">
    Right div
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you remove the answer approval?

Comment: Although adding 2 blank cols will "work" the offset class is a little more correct.

Comment: Thank You @JayD I thought so too. There is nothing "wrong" with the approved answer its just my answer is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

For a scalable solution I recommend:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 gauche">Left div</div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 corps">Right div</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;         
    justify-content: center;

    .col-* {
       display: inline-block;
       margin-left: -2px; /* Adjust the value of marging work best with your context */
       float: none;
    }
}
```

Now it won't matter how many columns (or types of columns) you put in `<div class="center"></div>`

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
.row {
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything.