# Bootstrap 3 - cannot center 2 equal sized `cols` in a `row` using an offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nbd2w3zb/

Using Bootstrap 3 and I have 2 equal sized columns (`.col-md-4`) within a `.row`.

The effect I want is to center both of these columns inside the `.row` such that there is an equal amount of space on the left of "Column A" and the right of "Column B".

It's also important there is space between "Column A" and "Column B" as shown on the screenshot - I do *not* want the borders joined.

I cannot understand how to use offsets to achieve this. No matter what I do, it doesn't ever give equal spacing on either side, and is thus off center:

[image]
I've read this post [Bootstrap: two column centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666532/bootstrap-two-column-centered) but the accepted answer seems to rely on putting in empty `div` tags, such that they add up to 12 columns. That seems like a terrible idea. The other solution uses offsets, but I can't get this to work no matter what numbers i use.

Surely this is possible in Bootstrap? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set offset of 1 on first column and 2 on second. This way you get `1 + 4 + 2 + 4 = 11` and one left on right side to 12. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nbd2w3zb/2/)

Comment: That's what I didn't understand though... I get that it adds up to 11. But where are you getting "and one left on right side to 12" from??

Comment: It's always 12 in one row so in your case you used 11 and there is one left.

Comment: Right. I find that really confusing. I understand the principle of things adding up to 12 in Bootstrap. But when you're writing markup without offsets, you can do quick calculations (e.g. three `.col-md-4` - you know that's just 3*4 = 12). But in this case it's like the numbers add up to 11 and then you've no idea just looking at the code what it's doing or how 11 is giving "equal" spacing in a 12 column setup. Confusing. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Its not that confusing if you think of it as 12 empty columns and no matter if you used col-something or offset-something you still used some number of columns and you always make sure that it doesn't go over 12 for one row.

Comment: Also there is another way to do this using flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/nbd2w3zb/6/