# Centering divs that span odd number of columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center two of my divs in Bootstrap 3's grid.  The problem is, together they span 9 columns, which is an odd number of columns.  My first div spans 6 columns, and the second one spans 3 columns. This leaves me with 3 extra columns for whitespace, but I'm not able to figure out how to divide this up equally to the left and right. I can either have 2 empty columns on the left and 1 on the right or the other way round.

For example, this gets left aligned:

```
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2"></div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div id="myFirstDiv"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div id="mySecondDiv"></div>
              </div>  

              <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
```

If there was a way to make the first column 1.5 and the last 1.5, that would be have been perfect. Is there anything I can do to center my content?

I have tried using center-block, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/how-do-i-center-a-bootstrap-div-with-a-spanx-class ... let me know if you're happy with the solution in that answer, and then maybe we can flag this to be closed as a dupe? In partic I'd go with the first comment, of defining a `.center` class that looks like `{ float: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }`

Comment: (there's a big answer in there about BS3, as well)

Comment: make your own grid system if existing is not what you need : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: Also, you don't need to have divs that are just Bootstrap columns with nothing in them to push content around in the row. Use Bootstrap's column offset feature: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting.

Comment: @sifriday, I tried using center-block which is the same as the .center comment, but that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a `.col-md-1andahalf` class?

Just create one, if that's what you need:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)/*or whatever*/{
.col-md-1-5 {
width: 12.5%;
}
 //.....
}
```

Comment: This approach seems to be the easiest for me.  However, I would need to extend one of the col-md classes in order to get this working right?  I am not using a SASS version of Bootstrap, so is it still possible to extend?

Comment: you just need to add it to grid system , if you have a local stylesheet add it following grid structure otherwise just add it like above (you could do the same in `lg` `sm` `xs` type ); be careful if you set a custom breakpoint

Comment: What is it that I have to add?

Comment: [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is the basic bootstrap css structure , it's made of `containers` - `rows`  and `col` ;  you need to create a new col type (study the documentation, it will save you time!!)...